# Twilio SMS logs mass export to CSV

Tags: csv, export, twilio

I am trying to export a large amount of SMS logs (about 250k records) from the Twilio API as a CSV file. I tried using the default export feature on the SMS dashboard, but it stops after 8k records. I then tried a Heroku app (https://github.com/jmadden/twilio-sms-log-export) to grab the logs from the Twilio API. This worked better, but it still times out after 55k-60k records. Can anyone recommend something that can handle such a large amount of data, or spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That's quite a lot of messages to download! My guess is that the Heroku app simply ran out of memory when putting the CSV together in process. I don't know why the dashboard CSV export didn't work for you. I'd recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to see if they can get the CSV working, or export it themselves for you.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I've submitted a ticket with Twilio Support, and hopefully they can help me with that.

Comment: If there's no help, then I have some ideas. Depends on what code you can run on the machine you want it downloaded to though. Let me know!